# Swapping files in java (delete-rename) fails

Tags: java, file-io

What i'm trying to do, is having two parameters to parse my users.txt file - find the entry (have already made a test beforehands knowing it's there) and make a new file (users_new.txt) which has the entry skipped.

After all is done, i want to delete the older file and keep the new one renaming it as the older one.

I have tested the code seperately in a new java file and it works perfectly.
On this scenario the delete/rename part won't work. Even though i run it and get the "true" flag as well as the tex files are changed, the swap won't be successfull.

Here's the code for the parsing.

```
boolean deleted = false;

    try {

        // open the users.txt file
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("users.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("users_new.txt");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer);

        String line = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split(" ");
            // only interested for duplicate usernames

            if (username.equals(values[0])) {
                // if we find the user, we  dont keep it in
                // the new temporary file
                // but have to mark the pointer as true, so we know it was found
                deleted = true;
                continue;
            }
            // keeping every other entry
            out.println(values[0] + " " + values[1]);

        }
        br.close();
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return deleted;
```

While i perform the delete as follows

```
 private static void swapFiles(){
    // needs some more careful approach. But for now..
    File inputFile = new File("users.txt");
    File outFile = new File("users_new.txt");

        if (inputFile.delete()) {
            outFile.renameTo(inputFile);
        }
}
```

and call it like this

```
 public static boolean delete(String key) {

    if (removeEntry(key)) {
        swapFiles();    
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

edit: Tried the other way round, and it works which is much weirder.

Comment: Just a remark, you can close only last wrapper of stream, i.e. `br` and `out`.

Comment: @Tzoiker Yeah, i  tried that way too just in case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems here that I can see:

1. not properly closing resources, this can cause buffers to not be flushed
2. using the old `File` API that has little to no feedback on failure.

From my understanding you want to do two, separate, tasks:

1. read file `orig`, and write the contents to file `new` - skipping the line that start with `username`
2. replace file `orig` with file `new`

The first method should look like this, notice the `try...finally` constructs - this provides a *guarantee* of correct closure:

```
public static void filter(final Path orig, final Path into, final Predicate<String> lineFilter) throws IOException {
    try (final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(orig);
         final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(into))) {
        lines.filter(lineFilter).forEach(pw::println);
    }
}
```

Now for the replacement file:

```
public static void moveAndDelete(final Path orig, final Path into) throws IOException {
    Files.move(into, orig, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

So to call the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Path users = Paths.get("users.txt");
    final Path newUsers = Paths.get("users_new.txt");
    final String username = "MyUser";
    filter(users, newUsers, s -> !s.startsWith(username));
    overwrite(newUsers, users);
}
```

The NIO methods throw appropriate exceptions when they cannot complete, rather than simply returning a `boolean`.

Comment: I'm sorry but you're writing your own code. I don't want to completely overhaul mine if i can't think like that.

Comment: @Rentonie that doesn't solve the fact that you have a number issues and that this is the code that you _should_ be writing.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the file is in use during the authentication before the delete.